# Bingo game database representation for scalability

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, database-design

This is my first scalability-related question.

In order to simplify the problem, I will use a bingo app idea:

We have a bingo application. Each users has a ticket with 15 random numbers out of 90. Each week the bingo is held to find the winner. Numbers are drawn **live** until there is a winner. Ex:

- 15th number is drawn -> search table -> no match
- 16th number is drawn -> search table -> no match
- ...
- 30th number is drawn -> search table -> winner -> stop

## Question 1:

Which way is better / faster for representing data in table and for searching that table? Table will have 10+ million rows

## Idea 1:

Table Tickets

```
id           user_id          week    ticket                                                 created
====================================================================================================
1            100022312        1       1,3,5,7,9,14,15,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84            <timestamp>
2            102232123        1       2,5,9,22,33,44,55,66,77,,78,79,80,88,89            <timestamp>
3            201141028        1       7,8,9,11,22,33,34,35,37,39,51,55,58,63,66          <timestamp>
...
9.000.000    126387125        1       8,18,28,38,48,58,68,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85        <timestamp>
10.000.000   126387126        1       1,4,14,24,34,45,56,66,67,68,79,80,81,82,83         <timestamp>
```

Php

```
$drawn_numbers = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,89,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22, ...';

$result = query("SELECT * FROM Tickets WHERE sksf('$drawn_numbers')");
```

where `sksf` would be some kind of substring function / regex / LIKE done in MySql.

## Idea 2:

Table Tickets

```
id           user_id          week    n1   n2   n3   ...   n15        created
=============================================================================
1            100022312        1       11   32   52   ...   76     <timestamp>
2            102232123        1       22   52   55         78     <timestamp>
3            201141028        1       77   82   83   ...   89     <timestamp>
...
9.000.000    126387125        1       81   55   32   ...   10     <timestamp>
10.000.000   126387126        1       12   42   13   ...   77     <timestamp>
```

Php

```
$drawn_numbers = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,89,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22, ...';

$result = query("SELECT * FROM Tickets WHERE contidion1 AND condition2 AND ...");
```

Unfortunately, here I still don't have any idea about the conditions.

## Idea 3:

I select all tickets, iterate though them by checking if the drawn numbers contain any ticket.

```
$drawn_numbers = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,89,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22, ...';
$all_tickets = query("SELECT * FROM Tickets");

foreach ($all_tickets as $ticket) {
    if $drawn_numbers.contains($ticket['ticket'])
        return $ticket['id'];
}
```

## Question 2:

Will having sorted numbers help in anyway? (Those 15 numbers and the drawn numbers)

## Question 3:

What happens when week 2 arrives? Should I use the same table, adding a condition `WHERE week=2`, or is it better to have only 1 week per table?

## Update

In the original game, a ticket has 15 numbers in 3 rows, each row having 5 numbers. After each number is drawn live, they are able to also calculate the tickets which have one row found in the drawn numbers (also they know the tickets with 2 rows). A ticket having 3 rows found in the drawn numbers would mean winning ticket.

This information makes me think that the representation looks something like:

## Idea 4:

Table Tickets

```
id           user_id          week    row1                row2                 row3                     created
===============================================================================================================
1            100022312         1      1, 3, 5, 7, 9       14,15,77,78,79,      80,81,82,83,84       <timestamp>
2            102232123         1      2, 5, 9,22,33,      44,55,66,77,78,      79,80,87,88,89       <timestamp>
3            201141028         1      7, 8, 9,11,22,      33,34,35,37,39,      51,55,58,63,66       <timestamp>
...
9.000.000    126387125         1      8,18,28,38,48,      58,68,78,79,80,      81,82,83,84,85       <timestamp>
10.000.000   126387126         1      1, 4,14,24,34,      45,56,66,67,68,      79,80,81,82,83       <timestamp>
```

## Example of ticket:

```
__  13  __  33  40  __  __  70  __
 2  __  22  37  __  52  62  __  81
__  19  23  __  44  __  63  __  89
```

## Example of drawn numbers (not necessarily in sorted order)

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 19, 23, 44, 63, 89
-> there is a winner, no more numbers are drawn.
-> Our ticket did not win jackpot, but we won one row [19, 23, 44, 63, 89] (free ticket)
-> One can win also 2 rows.
```

Comment: More rows, less columns - and no comma-separated values.

Comment: Can you explain why more rows less columns is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use two `BIGINT` columns, and have each bit represent one of the bingo values (1..90).  It will take a little bit of manipulation to construct a set of balls, but the searching will be easy, the storage will be *much* more compact, etc.

Let's have 2 columns, one with numbers 1..60, the other with 61..90.  (The choice is somewhat arbitrary, but makes it easy to visualize.)  Now we can do it with one `BIGINT` and one `INT`.

```
IF($value <= 60, 1 << $value, 0) -- the bit for the BIGINT
IF($value >  60, 1 << ($value - 60), 0)  -- the bit for the INT
```

Now or'ing together bits gives you a pair of numbers to represent a winning ticket.  Use the `|` Operator for this task.

Each player's current balls will also be or'd -- a new bit being turned on after each play.

Then the test becomes something like this:

```
-- The balls owned by a user:
user_60 BIGINT,
user_30 INT

-- winning balls (12 rows, a total of 5 bits on for each row)
win_60 BIGINT,
win_30 INT

-- Note: FREE SPACE should be pre-populated in both structures

BIT_COUNT(user_60 & win_60) +
BIT_COUNT(user_30 & win_30)  = 5  -- he's a winner!
```

I have left out an important step -- the arrangement of the numbers on each user's board.  That will takes some up-front work, especially since 15 of the numbers can only go in the first column of the card.  Etc.

Your takeaway from my Answer is to work with *bits* not other structures.

Another thought is to have 5 `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`, one for each column on the cards.

(For the future, in MySQL 8.0, `BINARY(16)` would allow a single column to represent a set of 90 values, thereby making the code cleaner.)

**re Idea 4**

Build 3 bit patterns - one per "row" with 5 numbers.  Compare them to the issued tickets:  Foreach ticket, compare the 3 patterns; count how many match.

Comment: This helps a lot. But I have one more question. Please check the update in the question. Then, would I be able to extract that information (1 row winnings and 2 row winnings) using your suggested representation?

Comment: @DonJoe - more of same.  I added to my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

One approach would be to [use a bitmap](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html) of the ticket numbers. You'd need 2 BIGINTs to store the values. If the AND of the ticket numbers and chosen numbers returns the same value as the ticket numbers, then you have a match. But you can't use an index for that.

If it's possible to win by matching only some of the numbers, then both the approaches you cited will be very innefficient - you need to normalize your data:

```
 create table ticket (
   id integer auto_increment,
   user_id /* appropriate type for FK to your data about users */,
   week_number integer,
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
 );
 create table numbers (
   number integer not null,
   ticket_id integer not null,
   FOREIGN KEY ticket_id references ticket(id)
 );
```

This looks like a carefully designed scenario to test out scalability approaches - are you asking us to do your homework here?

Comment: It's not homework. I just want to learn a little about scalable applications, and this example popped into my mind. I already built a script and populated a table for testing, but I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way. Also, I have already seen a bingo program which goes exactly like this, and I was wondering how do they find the winning ticket in around 3 seconds, out of millions of tickets...

Comment: Right now I am thinking: What about doing the opposite? I select all the tickets. Then, for each draw, I iterate though the tickets to see if any of them is included in the winning numbers... ?

Comment: I am also trying to learn better how a relational db works. That's why those kind of questions.

Comment: Drawing all the numbers is probably the most efficient solution - but then you need to think about how you store/evaluate the order (hint: with the normalized schema its relatively trivial but difficult with the other approaches)

Comment: By drawing all the numbers you mean selecting all the tickets from table?
This is the first time I heard about `normalization`, so I'd have to do some reading before I can use it.
About the bitmap method, can you try to explain in a little more? It was not very clear to me.

Comment: So it is just a thought experiment. Perhaps you should start with something a bit simpler.

Comment: It's not just a thought experiment. As I said, there already is a bingo program which goes exactly like this and I need to know how did they do so that it's that fast. After I find out, I can use similar approach to my project now and in the future.
I thought a lot about it. Looks like only `method 3` is the only one worth trying.